# Set up MySQL Database Connection With Netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: php, netbeans, ubuntu-11.04

Trying to integrate netbeans with mysql database management into the IDE as [explained here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html).

I am running Ubuntu 11.1 on my local machine with phpMyAdmin.

I have set the usr name and password and the correct port number, but I can't seem to set the path to the phpmyadmin in the admin tab.

I have tried /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php as well as /etc/phpmyadmin  .. both time I get a permission denied error and I am not entirely sure what file netbeans actually wants to work with.

Any Help would be truly appreciated..  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant run phpmyadmin as a command line tool so the URI you need would be to the installation on the local webserver like `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` ... whatever URL you use to access it in a browser on your machine.

That said I dont know why you would use PHP My Admin when you could use MySQL Workbench or one of the other GNOME or KDE admin apps. They are all pretty much superior :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help.. turns out the answer was hidden in plain sight just needed to click on the drivers folder.